# Storyboard To value staticresource

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, staticresource

Can figure this one out, I have some staticresources in aaplication.xaml

These staticresources i use in differtent places, per design. Now i want to use a Staticresource to a Coloranimation in a Storyboard but i can't get it to work i get the error: 
`An object of the type "System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "System.Nullable1[[System.Windows.Media.Color,....]]`

Code so far:

Application.XAML

```
<Application.Resources>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GreenLight" Color="#0CAF12" />
</Application.Resources>
```

In a usercontrol label style:

```
<Setter Property="Label.Content" Value="Connected" />
<DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <BeginStoryboard Name="StoryConnected">
          <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                 <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="{StaticResource GreenLight}" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
           </Storyboard>
     </BeginStoryboard>
</DataTrigger.EnterActions>
<DataTrigger.ExitActions>
      <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StoryConnected" />
</DataTrigger.ExitActions>
```

Comment: You can't assign a Brush to a property of type Color. Declare a Color resource instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't work because the `Storyboard` cannot be frozen when you bind the `To` property:

```
To="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource GreenLight}}"
```

So you actually need to set the `To` property to a `Color` object, i.e. define your resource like this:

```
<Color x:Key="GreenLight">#0CAF12</Color>
```